# Access database(oracle) using XML in java

Tags: java, xml, database, oracle

Is there any way to Access database from java using **XML**. I dont want to fire queries from my java code.I came to know about MLIP(Message Level Interface Port), but not much is available about it on internet.

Also got one link

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb01int.htm#g1054540

But not getting clarity.My application is using jsp and servlets with MVC architecture and cant migrate it to framework like struts and hibernate.

Comment: To use SQL, all you need is JDBC which is pretty basic.

Comment: but i dont want to fire queries in my java code.Rather i want to access it using XML. With basic jdbc i knw how to access database but not with xml

Comment: You need a library which will translate the XML into SQL.  This adds complexity, but can be done.  I don't know of any library which does this as SQL is pretty standard and the main alternative is JSon AFAIK, e.g. mongodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org) (formerly known as iBatis) is what is you looking for. It is a framework which eases accessing databases by extenalizing SQL queries in XML files and not Java code. So as far as your queries parameters and output are the same, you can manipulate manipulate them without need to change your Java code, or even recompiling it.

Answer (score 0):

XML is a mechanism for formatting data so that is can be exchanged between systems.  Although it is now used for other things it is not a database access protocol.

If you don't want to use JDBC then you must choose another protocol.  Oracle XML DB supports FTP, WebDAV and direct access through HTTP(S).  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb22pro.htm#ADXDB2500).

Answer (score 0):

You might got the answer from below link.

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r1/prod/datamgmt/xmldb/xmldb.htm

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid (and downvoted) if the linked page changes. See [How To Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) for why it is important.